# Prepend x/ to line where x is a variable on each line

Tags: bash, sed

I want to add `$x/` from data formatted as `$x-xyz` (`xyz` is a mix of text and number to be ignored).

**Example data**

```
AB-10C
CD-02E
```

**Output**

```
AB/AB-10C
CD/CD-02E
```

How do I describe the variable as text before the hyphen? My idea is:

```
define $x = # don't know how to do that
## and then somehow use sed to prepend
sed -i s/$/$x/ file
# I don't know if sed can handle variables though - the above one liner is from Googling
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty `awk` version:

```
awk -F- '{print $1"/"$0}' input_file > output_file
```

What it does is use `-` as a field separator, and prints the first column (i.e. everything before the first `-`), then a `/`, then the whole original line.

A way of doing the same thing with `sed` would be:

```
sed -e 's;^\([^-]*\)\(.*\);\1/\1\2;' input_file > output_file
```

(but that's hardly readable.)

If you want to do it in plain `bash`, you can use [string manipulations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
$ foo=AB-10C
$ prefix=${foo%%-*}
$ echo ${prefix}/${foo}
AB/AB-10C
```

Use that in a `while read` loop or similar if the data is coming from a file.

Comment: Though it was unintentional, I simplified the example a bit, and the results with the real data were interesting. The actual data was like `211,AB-45A,1`, and it got manipulated to `211,AB/211,AB-45A,1` with both awk and sed. Couldn't try pure bash since I'm not quite familiar with `while read` and didn't bother researching. Anyway, I separated the relevant data and it worked as expected - thank you!

Comment: For the while loop, just type "[bash] while read" in the search box at the top of this site. You'll get plenty of examples :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "123,AB-10C,4\n567,CD-02E,8" |
sed 's|\([^,]*\)-.*|\1/&|'
123,AB/AB-10C,4
567,CD/CD-02E,8
```